# Express.js / Node 0.12 res.setHeader undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've an express application running on node.js 0.12 which is clustered

When I try to run inside a middleware a `res.setHeader` i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'server' of undefined

_stream_readable.js:505
  dest.end();
     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Stream.onend (_stream_readable.js:505:10)
  at Stream.g (events.js:199:16)
  at Stream.emit (events.js:129:20)
  at _stream_readable.js:908:16
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I've spent the last days trying to figure out what's happening, but the application is properly initialized. It's running inside a function because the application is `cluster`ed.

Of course I'm unable to use any function which tries to set an header inside my application because of this error, this is just a test I've made to figure out what's the problem.

Any idea?
For completeness here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/JRPGBJKb) of the application file, called by `cluster` (only by workers).

Comment: Creating a new, simple application doesn't make this error happen, really not understanding what's happening here...

Comment: Ought... I found it to be an issue related to http2 module, checking for some info... it's weird that it was working since last time I "npm cache clean"'ed